# Random variable controlling color isn't changing every time the for loop happens

Tags: javascript

my code is working creating a line diagonally forward and down but the light color never changes, it always just stays red. Can anyone help me fix this? BTW the red part is from earlier in the code meaning that none of the if statements are working in the loop
[the code controls the lights on the right side of the house](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QTNn.png)

```
function lightsDown(x,y,ln,s) {

for (u = 0; u < ln; u++) {
    
    var c = random(1,4)
    
    if (c === 1) {
        
        fill('green')
        
    } 
    if (c === 2) {
        fill ('red')
    }
    if (c === 3) {
        fill('yellow')
    }
    if (c === 4) {
        fill('blue')
    }
        
    circle((x+4.5*s)-(2.67*s/ln)*u,y-(2.67*s/ln*u), s/4)
    
}
```

}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're condition on the if statement seems wrong. It should be (c === 1). And converting the variable c to int.

Comment: still doesn't work I updated the page showing what it does

Comment: it's because the random function returns a float. You should try converting it to int using Math.floor

Answer (score 0):

Random returns a decimal number convert it to a integer with:

```
var c = math.floor(random(1, 4))
```